# How can a datapump export have its resource usage limited on windows?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, datapump, export, windows

Doing an export of a number of users causes high CPU and I/O usage. I can mitigate the effects of the CPU usage using Resource Manager and setting the export session to a low priority group, but how can I limit the disk I/O? I am not running the operation in parallel and have already read Oracle's Datapump Performance documentation. Is there anything else I can do?

This is on Windows 2008 R2 x64.

Comment: My problem turned out to be specifically with the initial stages of the export before it starts writing to the export files.  I upgraded to 11.2.0.2 from 11.2.0.1, switched to statistical estimating and throttled the method to the lowest resource manager group and that seemed to solve the problem.  The other answers to this question may be useful for others.

Comment: Leigh add that as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Send it over the network**

While extensive searching found no way to limit disk io natively (and serverFault will probably have more details on that) a "natural" way of limiting IO is to send the output directly across the network without ever touching the local disk. This then allows you to take advantage of all the network IO throttling resources out there. (If you want to be really sneaky, try to set up the network resource on the local machine, but that may be an overly-cute solution.)

Comment: +1 Great idea, unfortunately I'm already writing directly to a network share.  I suppose I could request a remote drive on a slower disk or from a server with a slower network connection, but from my testing it looks like the problem is mostly at the start of the export when it is determining what/how much data is being exported.  I changed from block estimates to statistics estimates, but that still didn't help enough.

Comment: Nono, if you're writing directly to a network share, use something like: http://serverfault.com/questions/14806/limit-transfer-speed-on-windows-2008 to limit the throughput of the link.

Comment: Not the answer to my specific problem, but certainly a good answer to the question as presented.

Answer (score 1):

**De-tune the datapump**

The [docs list](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16536/dp_perf.htm#i1005665) a number of methods for *improving* the performance of a data pump, including suggested alterations to the SGA, and considerations about encryption and compression. By inverting this advice, especially about compression and SGA, and then limiting CPU usage, IO usages may be reduced as a consequence.

Comment: Nice idea, but it seems that undoing most performance improving devices would decrease overall database performance not just the datapump operation making this unacceptable.

Answer (score 0):

My problem turned out to be specifically with the initial stages of the export before it starts writing to the export files. I upgraded to 11.2.0.2 from 11.2.0.1, switched to statistical estimating and throttled the method to the lowest resource manager group and that seemed to solve the problem. The other answers to this question may be useful for others.